# Mass create attributes for Magento

Tags: attributes

So I am dealing with a group of products that have around 30+ different attributes. When I import the CSV file of the products magento doesn't create the attributes automatically. From there, it seems I would have to manually create each attribute one at a time? Is there a way to mass create say around 30 different attributes all at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in the root of your Magento install. Paste the following code:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $_product) 
{
    echo "\n".'updating '.$_product->getSku()."...\n";
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
    $product->setData('your_attribute_to_update_here', 1)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'your_attribute_to_update_here');
}
```

Goto yourstore.com/script-aboves-name.php

Keep in mind, the `1` in `('your_attribute_to_update_here', 1)` can also be a string: `"string"`

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in a new file and placed it in the root folder. When I go to mystore.com/your-php-code.php it will stay on a screen with updating 123...

Comment: Did you update your attribute and value in the code first?

Comment: Here is what I had added to your code:
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app ()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $_product) 
{
    echo "\n".'updating '.$_product->getSku()."...\n";
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
    $product->setData('MassAttributeTest', 1)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'MassAttributeTest');
}
?>